# pandas dataframe, ranking by values within another column, without using a Python FOR loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each value of one column ('date' in my example below), I want to rank by the value in another column (the 'value' column in my example)

My code works, but I wonder if it can be done without the Python for loop

```
data = {'code': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'CCC'],
        'date': ['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03'],
        'value': [32, 23, 34, 23, 34, 12, 28, 39, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
result = pd.DataFrame()
for date in df['date'].unique():
    sub = df[df['date'] == date]
    sub['rank'] = len(sub) - sub['value'].rank() + 1
    result = result.append(sub[['code', 'date', 'rank']])
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'warn')
df2 = pd.merge(df, result, on=['code', 'date'])

print(df2.sort_values(['date', 'code']))  # within each date, rows are ranked by value
```

```
  code        date  value  rank
0  AAA  2001-01-01     32   1.0
3  BBB  2001-01-01     23   3.0
6  CCC  2001-01-01     28   2.0
1  AAA  2001-01-02     23   3.0
4  BBB  2001-01-02     34   2.0
7  CCC  2001-01-02     39   1.0
2  AAA  2001-01-03     34   2.0
5  BBB  2001-01-03     12   3.0
8  CCC  2001-01-03     40   1.0
```

Can I get the same result without iterating through a Python for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `rank` with `groupby` then

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('code')['value'].rank()
df
Out[491]: 
  code        date  value  rank
0  AAA  2001-01-01     32   2.0
1  AAA  2001-01-02     23   1.0
2  AAA  2001-01-03     34   3.0
3  BBB  2001-01-01     23   2.0
4  BBB  2001-01-02     34   3.0
5  BBB  2001-01-03     12   1.0
6  CCC  2001-01-01     28   1.0
7  CCC  2001-01-02     39   2.0
8  CCC  2001-01-03     40   3.0
```

Comment: Check out my second answer.  I'm proud of it but have to stress test it.

Comment: @piRSquared nice solution Sir, 2nd one should be faster than the argsort ~!

Comment: Got it!  Posted timing too.  Now I just have to try to remember it.

Answer (score 2):

#### `argsort`

Used creatively

```
def rank(s):
    n = len(s)
    a = s.to_numpy().argsort()
    b = np.empty_like(a)
    b[a] = np.arange(n)
    return b + 1

df.assign(rank=df.groupby('code').value.transform(rank))

  code        date  value  rank
0  AAA  2001-01-01     32     2
1  AAA  2001-01-02     23     1
2  AAA  2001-01-03     34     3
3  BBB  2001-01-01     23     2
4  BBB  2001-01-02     34     3
5  BBB  2001-01-03     12     1
6  CCC  2001-01-01     28     1
7  CCC  2001-01-02     39     2
8  CCC  2001-01-03     40     3
```

---

#### `lexsort` and `unique`

Even more creative and no longer needs `groupby`.
This should be pretty quick.  I have to test this somehow on bigger data.

```
def rank_grouped(s, groups):
    n = len(s)
    x = s.to_numpy()
    y = groups.to_numpy()
    a = np.lexsort([x, y])
    b = np.empty_like(a)
    r = np.arange(n)

    t, i, j = np.unique(y[a], return_inverse=True, return_index=True)

    b[a] = r - i[j] + 1
    
    return b

df.assign(rank=rank_grouped(df.value, df.code))

  code        date  value  rank
0  AAA  2001-01-01     32     2
1  AAA  2001-01-02     23     1
2  AAA  2001-01-03     34     3
3  BBB  2001-01-01     23     2
4  BBB  2001-01-02     34     3
5  BBB  2001-01-03     12     1
6  CCC  2001-01-01     28     1
7  CCC  2001-01-02     39     2
8  CCC  2001-01-03     40     3
```

---

#### Timing

Big Dataset

```
np.random.seed([3, 14])
n = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code': np.random.randint(10_000, size=n),
    'value': np.random.randn(n)
})

%timeit df.assign(rank=df.groupby('code').value.transform(rank))
%timeit df.assign(rank=df.groupby('code')['value'].rank())
%timeit df.assign(rank=rank_grouped(df.value, df.code))

1.29 s ± 7.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
367 ms ± 3.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
294 ms ± 2.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Bonus tutorial on .transform(rank) much appreciated